# Internal Connection Fatal Error when using EF Core but not Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Tags: .net, sql-server, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to get a ASP.NET Core project working with SQL Server, instead of just the SQLite I've been using for testing thus far. I've installed SQL Server 2019 Express on my machine to test with, but I've run into the issue that when using EF Core, I can't connect to the database as it fails with the error

> Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error

The full exception information is at the bottom.

The connection string I'm using is:

```
Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=webTools;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=true
```

I have verified the database exists and that my user account has permissions to it. Running

```
sqlcmd -S localhost\SQLEXPRESS -E -d webTools
```

works without error and I can create tables and add entries to them from the command line.

I verified the connection string works by creating a small test program:

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

string connectionString = "Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=webTools;TrustServerCertificate=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true;Integrated Security=true";

string queryString = "SELECT name, create_date FROM sys.databases";
await using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await using SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
    command.Connection.Open();
    await using var data = await command.ExecuteReaderAsync();

    while (await data.ReadAsync())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1}", data[0], data[1]);
        // Console.WriteLine(data[1]);
    }
}
```

This small test program works correctly, outputting real data.

To be sure the first project wasn't misconfigured, I followed [Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio-code) and created a new project. That project failed, with the following output:

```
Entity Framework Core 6.0.7 initialized 'SchoolContext' using provider 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer:6.0.7' with options: None
Unhandled exception. System.InvalidOperationException: Internal connection fatal error.
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.CompleteLogin(Boolean enlistOK)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData, Boolean applyTransientFaultHandling, String accessToken, DbConnectionPool pool) 
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)   at Microsoft.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open(SqlConnectionOverrides overrides)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.<>c__DisplayClass18_0.<Exists>b__0(DateTime giveUp)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass12_0`2.<Execute>b__0(DbContext c, TState s)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerExecutionStrategy.Execute[TState,TResult](TState state, Func`3 operation, Func`3 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ExecutionStrategyExtensions.Execute[TState,TResult](IExecutionStrategy strategy, TState state, Func`2 operation, Func`2 verifySucceeded)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean retryOnNotExists)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.Storage.Internal.SqlServerDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalDatabaseCreator.EnsureCreated()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.DatabaseFacade.EnsureCreated()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\username\source\test\webapp\Program.cs:line 34
```

It would seem to me that when trying to use EF Core, there's something that I'm doing wrong that isn't needed when using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient directly.

Comment: Is the ASP.NET Core web project actually executing with your credentials? If it were running under IIS 7 or later, for example, the code would be executing with the Application Pool's identity which is a member of the IIS_IUSRS group. Can you get it to login successfully by using User ID and Password connection string properties for an SQL Login?

Comment: Side note: should be `await connection.OpenAsync();`

Comment: (sorry for the late response) I tried with using a SQL login, it similarly works with a Microsoft.Data.SqlClient but doesn't with EF Core. The exceptions are identical, with an "Internal connection fatal error" result.